# Scrolling in Emacs without ever moving point, even if off-screen

Tags: emacs, scroll

I want to configure Emacs to scroll my buffer without moving point, even if it goes off-screen. In my current setup, when I do `(scroll-up 4)` for long enough, my point will eventually be moved to keep it within the visible buffer.

I want to change this because `idle-highlight` will color in a symbol for me and I want to see its occurrence. When I scroll far enough, my point is moved just before it would go off-screen and `idle-highlight` backs off. How can I change this?

I'm using Emacs 24.

Comment: I use split-window and scroll-other-window(C-M-v), scroll-other-window-down(C-M-S-v) in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this scrolling. But a optional solution is to use the `highlight-symbol` package. Check this:[Highlight Symbol](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/). If you want to try, just press: `M-x package-install highlight-mode`

1. This package can do a idle highlight too, `M-x highlight-symbol-mode`, you can customize
   its delay.
2. If you want to highlight persistently, `M-x highlight-symbol-at-point`, then it will highlight the symbol at point the the whole buffer. `M-x highlight-symbol-remove-all` will clear all the highlight in the whole buffer.

Not exactly a solution to your question, hope that help :-)